# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML') Even With Script Tag After All Elements In My Body Tag

Tags: javascript, html

I keep getting the **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')** error in my console with the **script tag** at the end of my **body tag** beneath all **divs** and other elements. The error is only on user & opponent divs in the HTML and with the **userPic.innerHTML** and **oppPic.innerHTML**

```
  <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="header">
                <h1 class="title">Codys Pokemon Game</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="game" class="game">
                <input class="gameBtn" type="button" onclick="choose1()" value="CLICK TO START">
                <input class="infoBtn" type="button" onclick="info()" value="CLICK FOR GAME INFO">
            </div>

            <div class="user"></div>
            <div class="opponent"></div>

        </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

My **script.js** file shouldn't have any errors but if it does, this is the part where I add a bunch of stuff to my HTML:

```
    gameHTML.innerHTML = `<h2 class="gameInfo">Choose Your Attack</h2>`
    gameHTML.innerHTML += `<div class="userHp"><br>Your Health: ${pokemon1[1]}</div>`
    gameHTML.innerHTML += `<input class="att1" type="button" onclick="attack1()" value="Use: Attack: ${curPmon[4]}">`
    gameHTML.innerHTML += `<input class="att2" type="button" onclick="attack2()" value="Use: Attack: ${curPmon[5]}">`
    gameHTML.innerHTML += `<input class="att3" type="button" onclick="attack3()" value="Use: Attack: ${curPmon[6]}">`
    gameHTML.innerHTML += `<div class="oppHp"><br>Opponent Health: ${curOpp[1]}</div>`
    userPic.innerHTML += curPmon[7]
    oppPic.innerHTML += `<img src="${curOpp[7]}" alt="${curOpp[0]}">`
```

These are the variables I have for the IDs:

```
var gameHTML = document.getElementById('game')
var userPic = document.getElementById('user')
var oppPic = document.getElementById('opponent')
```

Comment: where have you defined `plkemon1` because while executing I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: pokemon1 is not defined`? You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: oh, I have it defined somewhere else, but the ones above the bottom 2 .innerHTML statements are all working, and the bottoms aren't working for some reason

Comment: I can give you the link to the website where its on if you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `user` and `opponent` are class, but you use `document.getElementById('user')`.
This is some advice

1. use `document.getElementsByClassName('user')` or `document.querySelector('.user')` instead
2. use `<div id="user"></div>` instead `<div class="user"></div>`

Comment: Thanks. I was just using a keybind to create the divs and that was one thing I forgot to check.

Comment: It's normal. Double check before code typing. Organize thoughts. Step by step.